# Tweet Tokenizing A column in Dataframe ; Getting Error

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, tokenize

I have a dataset with comment_texts. I want to tokenize these using code below:

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
tt = TweetTokenizer()

df['tokenized_text'] = df["comment_text"].apply(tt.tokenize)
```

I am getting below error by doing it:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-32-2e7f772f11fe> in <module>
      2 tt = TweetTokenizer()
      3 
----> 4 df['tokenized_text'] = df["comment_text"].apply(tt.tokenize)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)    3846             else:    3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)    3849     3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/casual.py in tokenize(self, text)
    293         """
    294         # Fix HTML character entities:
--> 295         text = _replace_html_entities(text)
    296         # Remove username handles
    297         if self.strip_handles:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/casual.py in
_replace_html_entities(text, keep, remove_illegal, encoding)
    257         return "" if remove_illegal else match.group(0)
    258 
--> 259     return ENT_RE.sub(_convert_entity, _str_to_unicode(text, encoding))
    260 
    261 

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

The data I am using is train set of Kaggle competition: https://www.kaggle.com/c/jigsaw-multilingual-toxic-comment-classification/data

Comment: can you post the top 5 rows in your question? from my assumption if the column data type is an `object` data type you may need to fill the missing values

Comment: Pandas often uses NaN for missing values, and trying to tokenize a NaN should raise that exception.